# Passing a vector as argument to function

Tags: c++, function, stl

I have a function like this:

```
void Foo(std::vector<bool> Visited, int actual element);
```

I actually use this function for a BFS in a Graph, but it goes in an infinite loop. I suspect it always creates a copy of the Visited vector. 
How do I make it change the vector, which is declared and initialized somewhere in main? And am I right with the whole "makes a copy" theory?

How do I use a pointer to an object, as I think `<vector>` is an object?

Comment: Yes it passes a copy, you could change the signature to `void Foo(std::vector<bool>& Visited, int actual element);` to be able to modify the vector within the function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value As far as your infinite loop, we cannot help you without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the referenced type

```
void Foo(std::vector<bool> &Visited, int actual element);
```

Otherwise the function deals with a copy of the original vector.

Here is a dempnstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void f( std::vector<int> &v )
{
    v.assign( { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } );
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    f( v );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass it by ***reference***:

```
void Foo(std::vector<bool>& Visited, int actual element); 
                          ^
```

Now you can modify the original vector passed to `Foo`.

> And am I right with the whole "makes a copy" theory?

Yes. Declaring the parameter with no `&` or `*` passes the object by **value** = as a copy. The same applies to return types etc. (With the exception of move constructors)